# Sending JSON data and Image to Server

Tags: android, json, image, asynchronous

I'm not sure if I'm taking the correct course in trying to achieve my objective.

I'm trying to send both JSON data and an image to a server. When the user clicks on a button the async call activates, gathers the JSON container that has the data and gets the image path. Here's is what I have so far:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... data) {
            gatherEditTextStringValue();

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            try {
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postVars = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postVars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("JSON", String.valueOf(JSONMainContainer)));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postVars));

                if (questionTitleImageUri != null) {
                    questionTitleImageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(questionTitleImageUri));
                    FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(questionTitleImageFile);
                    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
                    reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile1", bin1);
                    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
                }

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return responseBody;
        }
```

Now the problem is that I can send either or, not both. Is there a way to append the image data to the setEntity so that its aggregates both of them? Thank ye.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930071/how-to-construct-a-multipart-mime-request-and-post-it-using-angularjs-http-met  try a multipart post, loading your json into one of the parms

Comment: your multipart contains only one item. You need to add `reqEntity.addPart("json_data", new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postVars));`. Also, you don't really need `UrlEncodedFormEntity`. You could use `new StringEntity(String.valueOf(JSONMainContainer))` (in both cases).

Comment: as a side note, your server probably does not expect to have both multipart and not-multipart requests. You may want to stick with multipart in both cases, and only add the required parts.

Comment: @njzk2 Hey thanks for the pointer. I tried to add the JSON data to the multipart entity but its giving me a "wrong 2nd argument type" error. The parameter is expecting mime type objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add both parameters to `MultipartEntity` instead of calling `setEntity` two times because second call of `setEntity` method will override first method call settings do it as:

```
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
// add file
reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile1", bin1);
// add JSON String 
reqEntity.addPart("JSON", new StringBody(String.valueOf(JSONMainContainer)));
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works!

Comment: Thanks Man You are Star.